# How to convert Future<bool> into Stream<bool>

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter app, I have a function returning `Future`, but I wanna get result as `Stream`. Here is the function :

```
  Future<bool> isGpsOn() async {
    if (await Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

How to do that?

Comment: Where are you calling `isGpsOn()`..?

Comment: Its in my repository layer. I wanna use it in Bloc pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [manual](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch) and check my answer:

```dart
Stream<bool> gpsStatusStream() async* {
  bool enabled;
  while (true) {
    try {
      bool isEnabled = await Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled();
      if (enabled != isEnabled) {
        enabled = isEnabled;
        yield enabled;
      }
    }
    catch (error) {}
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  }
}
```

```dart
gpsStatusStream().listen((enabled) {
  print(enabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled');
});
```

or create convertor:

```dart
Stream futureToStream(fn, defaultValue, Duration duration) async* {
  var result;
  while (true) {
    try {
      result = await fn();
    }
    catch (error) {
      result = defaultValue;
    }
    finally {
      yield result;
    }
    await Future.delayed(duration);
  }
}
```

```dart
Future<bool> isGpsOn() async {
  return await Geolocator().isLocationServiceEnabled();
}
```

```dart
final gpsStatusStream = futureToStream(isGpsOn, false, Duration(seconds: 5));
gpsStatusStream.listen((enabled) {
  print(enabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: "await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));"  why this delay? Please explain.

Comment: @Newaj You can remove it, it’s just to show that it’s continuous stream of events. Cause You’re trying to get stream, it’s not one-shot thing.

Comment: @Newaj also I’ve added this delay to avoid checking the state of gps too often

Comment: It keeps calling the function. But I want it to call as soon as GPS status changes. Something like StreamBuilder.

Comment: @Newaj it’s based on manual calling that geolocator service. ok, I’m changing my answer to state when it changes.

Comment: @Newaj so I’ve made it to keep last state and if it changes to emit event. check updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the return type of your function, you could make callers convert the `Future<T>` to a `Stream<T>` by simply calling [`asStream()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-async/Future/asStream.html) on the returned `Future`.